# iOS: crash on presenting MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have only a short piece of code that should present a mail view with certain details, and when called

```
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The application crashes, saying `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`

I'm not sure whats causing this crash. I'm providing the code below.

```
NSString* encryptedText = [self getEncryptedText:noteText.text :cipherField.text];

MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; controller.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;

[controller setSubject:titleField.text];
[controller setMessageBody:encryptedText isHTML:NO];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thanks

Comment: try `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you create the `MFMailComposeViewController` make sure to check the user has their mail set up on their device by adding

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    //Place your code here to create the controller and present

}
```

If you try to present a `MFMailComposeViewController` on a device that has no mail set up already, then the app will crash. Adding this condition will detect this.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. It worked on my iPhone but I couldn't understand why it doesn't work on family iPad. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *composeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [composeViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [composeViewController setToRecipients:@[@""]];
        [composeViewController setSubject:@"Hi Test"];
        [composeViewController setMessageBody:@"Hello Test" isHTML:YES];

        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```